# What is this in nginx log? "\x01\x01..."

Tags: nginx, http

There are a lot of requests like this in our logs:

```
[07/Dec/2015:19:37:03 +0000] "\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\!
x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01" 400 172 "-" "-" "-"
```

I guess this a security vulnerability, but I could not find with Google. Has anyone else seen this or know what it is?

Comment: Welcome to wild internet. Someone sends bad request to you and nginx send 400 error code back. It's OK.

Comment: But you might want to find out IP who send these requests and contact with them to stop it. Or just firewall these request, or do something else

Comment: Thanks. These are coming from China or Taiwan. We are not worried about these requests, only curious which application's which vulnerability they are trying to exploit.

Comment: Directly related on security.se : [Server attack with \x01](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/124776/server-attack-with-x01)

Comment: This is pretty normal. In the future you can mitigate malicious attacks with tools like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) instead of worrying about manual firewall rules.

Comment: You might want to set `log_not_found off` in nginx.conf to block out the noise.

Answer (score 2):

It may be an attempt at exploiting a security vulnerability, but there is nothing in that log entry suggesting your server is vulnerable.

The client isn't speaking HTTP. It's just sending a sequence of bytes which all have value 1. If it was HTTP it would be interpreted as ASCII characters, and the 1 byte in ASCII is a rarely used control character, which has no meaning in HTTP.

It could be an attempt to exploit a buffer overflow, but if that's the case it would appear your server rejected the request as invalid before it even got to the malicious payload. On a vulnerable server it is quite likely nothing would have been logged.

The `400` in the log indicates that your server rejected the request as invalid. That's because a stream of 1 bytes isn't a valid HTTP method, and besides it's way too long.

An [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/124783/47143) to a related question on a sister site points out that this kind of request may also be an attempt at fingerprinting your server to find out what software it is running.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone is requesting some shellcode from your webserver.

I'd usually just ignore it, but if it's causing a problem with logging or something, ban them.

Do a quick Whois on their IP address and if it's a university, report it to the abuse@ email with logs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you had set `proxy_pass https://upstream;` while your upstream server was just listening on `http` port, if the upstream server was also an nginx server, its access log would be like what you have posted above.